# How can I render my own tiles using data I get with cartodb's core API library?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am trying to use the cartodb.core.js library to render my own tiles. According to what I see, the Tiles library is only available in the cartodb.core.js. And if we use that we don't get the createLayer function, which is fine if I can just get the Tiles to load, and I can render them myself:

```
var layerData = {
  user_name: 'swc28',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: "SELECT * FROM zoning",
    cartocss: '#layer { marker-fill: #F0F0F0; }'
  }]
};
cartodb.Tiles.getTiles(layerData, function(tiles, err) {
  if(tiles == null) {
    console.log("error: ", err.errors.join('\n'));
  }
  console.log("url template is ", tiles.tiles[0]);
})
```

But I've never rendered layers like this myself, and I looked at the library without much  success to figure out how to do it. So my question is: How does the CartoDB UI library render the tiles from a template url that is returned form the call above?

The template url looks like this:

```
http://{s}.ashbu.cartocdn.com/swc28/api/v1/map/fad6aaab9c3d921f76e0e07f3da6071f:1414011659683.92/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?cache_policy=persist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the mapping library you are using, each one has its own way to add tiled layers.

For example for leaflet the way to do this would be:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.ashbu.cartocdn.com/swc28/api/v1/map/fad6aaab9c3d921f76e0e07f3da6071f:1414011659683.92/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?cache_policy=persist').addTo(map)
```

I've created a full example.

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/leaflet_core_library.html

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if it's possible to also simulate the featureOver events of the vis library with this approach.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use leaflet utfgrid plugin and the urls cartodb provides for interaction